# Do all black holes mergers and kilonovae produce chirp?

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves, neutron-stars, ligo

It seems to me that during the final merger of 2 massive objects there will be a chirp, a sharp increase in the intensity and then it is cut off signaling the merging process is completed. I am wondering what factors help determine the shape of the chirp? is it the drastic difference in their masses or their angular momentum as they merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chirps are a generic feature of the merger of compact objects driven by the emission of gravitational waves. The general shape of the chirp is determined by the leading weak field approximation of the process, and is determined by a combination of the component masses known as the "[chirp mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_mass)":

$$ \mathcal{M}=\frac{(m_1 m_2)^{3/5}}{(m_1+m_2)^{1/5}}$$

However, the exact shape will obtain additional corrections depending on the individual mass, spins, and the (potential) presence of eccentricity and precession in the orbit.

Although, chirps are a generic feature compact object mergers there are exceptions. Some examples include:

1. For black hole-neutron star binaries in certain mass-ratio ranges, the neutron star will be torn apart by tidal forces before the actual merger, leading to a drastic change in the gravitational wave signal.
2. [The merger of a stellar mass compact object with a supermassive black hole with near-extremal spin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.01221) feature a long nearly monochromatic slowly decaying final phase instead of a chirp.